# LinqToSql C# and autoincrementing identity field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, identifier, ssms

I've got a problem, while trying to insert a new row into a SQL Server database with help of LINQ to SQL.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuestionsAnswers(UserQuestion userQuestion)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newUserQuestion = new QuestionAnswer();

            newUserQuestion.Question = userQuestion.Question;
            newUserQuestion.From = userQuestion.From;

            ViewBag.QuestionSent = true;
            QuestionAnswerDb.QuestionAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(newUserQuestion);
            QuestionAnswerDb.SubmitChanges();
            return View(AnswersList);
        }

        ViewBag.QuestionSent = false;
        ViewBag.From = userQuestion.From;
        ViewBag.Question = userQuestion.Question;
        return View(AnswersList);
}
```

And I get an error while trying to "submit" a new `UserQuestion` (that has only `From` and `Question` in it), QuestionAnswer has columns: `Id, From, Question, Answer` (this one is nullable):

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'QuestionAnswer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I thought that Linq-to-SQL should handle Identity autoincrement columns by itself. Now I think, that I was wrong...

Any clues on how to properly set an Id for this object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a field(usually an id field) set to have an identity in your database. Linq does not do this for you automatically. You can do this by:

```
 Open your table in Sql Server Management Studio
 right click Design
 Open up Column Properties under the field you want to set as your identity(ID)
 Expand Identity Specification
 Set (Is Identity) to Yes.
```

Comment: While i was creating a database, i've already set "Is Identity" to Yes, and it became autoincrementing automaticly.

Comment: @Kamilius Are you sure it is still so? Please verify because it can't hardly be true.

Comment: And here you were right. I've changed/did it in SQL Management Studio, but didn't "updated" generated class.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting id to null explicitly.  It is probably being set to 0 implicitly.

Comment: I can't do that, because field "Id" in DB is not a nullable int type, as is the field of model of type int (which can not receive value of "null")